# submit and display checkboxes values without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've a sort of e-commerce and in the checkout page I display the price.

In the same page, I've some "services" to add to the final price and this are showed with checkboxes.

Now I want that when I click on a checkbox the price will be updated with a sum.

Something like this: 'price' + 'service_1' + 'service_2' = total price

and I want that the services will be displayed in the other div dynamically

My problem is that i don't know how to update the price and display it in a div without a submit button.

```html
<form id="services" name="services-form" data-name="services Form">
  <div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="service_1" name="checkbox" data-name="Checkbox" class="checkbox 1 w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox" class="simple-text white w-form-label">design pack</label>22500 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field ew w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="service_2" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_2" class="checkbox 2 w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-2" class="simple-text white w-form-label">security</label>2000 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field 2 w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="service_3" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_3" class="checkbox 3 w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="simple-text white w-form-label">wellness pack</label>5000 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field 4 w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="service_4" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_4" class="checkbox 4 w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="simple-text white w-form-label">box auto</label>1000 €</div>
</form>

<div class="paragraph" id="price">
  <?php echo $price;?> €</div>
<div id="display_services" class="simple-text maiusc prova">services:<br>design pack<br>dynamically adding the services...</div>
```

Comment: **HINT** use `Ajax`

Comment: You only need AJAX if the prices are not already in the page. If they are, just use onclick and have a span with the total and update the innerHTML or  innerText with the sum of checked boxes values

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, yes, the prices are already in the page.. i've edited the code.. so can you just give me some more info on how to do the onclick? my boss asked me something that I usually don't do (js) and i'm in panic.

Comment: Please see my update. You also likely want to make sure the IDs are correct. You have some inconsistencies

Comment: thanks @mplungjan it worked!I don't want to take advantage of your kindness, but, it's possible to diplay the name in the div with id=display services dynamically?

Comment: @StefanoZanetti Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the values to the checkboxes - also make sure your IDs are correct and the for="ID" matches the checkbox. You have some inconsistencies - for example each label has the wrong "for" You need to have `<label for="someId"`

Updated answer using map and delegation of the eventListener

```js
const form = document.getElementById("services");
const serverPrice = parseInt(document.getElementById("price").innerText); // initial price
form.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let total = 0;
  const services = [...document.querySelectorAll("#services input[id^=service]:checked")] // all checked id="service..." boxes
    .map(chk => {
      total += +chk.value; 
      return document.querySelector(`[for="${chk.id}"]`).innerHTML
    })
  document.getElementById("price").innerText = (serverPrice + total) + "€";
  document.getElementById("display_services").innerHTML = "services: " + services.join(", ");
})
```

```html
<form id="services" name="services-form" data-name="services Form">
  <div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="22500" id="service_1" name="checkbox" data-name="Checkbox" class="checkbox 1 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_1" class="simple-text white w-form-label">design pack</label> 22500 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field ew w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2000 " id="service_2" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_2" class="checkbox 2 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_2" class="simple-text white w-form-label">security</label> 2000 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field 2 w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="5000" id="service_3" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_3" class="checkbox 3 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_3" class="simple-text white w-form-label">wellness pack</label> 5000 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field 4 w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1000" id="service_4" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_4" class="checkbox 4 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_4" class="simple-text white w-form-label">box auto</label> 1000 €</div>
</form>

<div class="paragraph" id="price">
  200 €</div>
<div id="display_services" class="simple-text maiusc prova">services:<br>design pack<br>dynamically adding the services...</div>
```

Older answer with for loop

```js
var serverPrice = parseInt(document.getElementById("price").innerText); // initial price
var checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[id^=service]"); // all id="service..." boxes
for (var i=0;i<checks.length;i++) {
  checks[i].onclick=function() {
    var services = [], total = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<checks.length;i++) { // again we loop
      if (checks[i].checked) { // a ternary is no longer useful
        total += +checks[i].value;
        services.push(document.querySelector("[for="+checks[i].id+"]").innerHTML); // get the label text
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("price").innerText=(serverPrice+total)+"€";
    document.getElementById("display_services").innerHTML="services: "+services.join(", ");
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="services" name="services-form" data-name="services Form">
  <div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="22500" id="service_1" name="checkbox" data-name="Checkbox" class="checkbox 1 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_1" class="simple-text white w-form-label">design pack</label> 22500 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field ew w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2000 " id="service_2" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_2" class="checkbox 2 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_2" class="simple-text white w-form-label">security</label> 2000 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field 2 w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="5000" id="service_3" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_3" class="checkbox 3 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_3" class="simple-text white w-form-label">wellness pack</label> 5000 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field 4 w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1000" id="service_4" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_4" class="checkbox 4 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_4" class="simple-text white w-form-label">box auto</label> 1000 €</div>
</form>

<div class="paragraph" id="price">
  200 €</div>
<div id="display_services" class="simple-text maiusc prova">services:<br>design pack<br>dynamically adding the services...</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should build me a house?

Comment: ahaha i could! if you help me to solve another problem.. as you can see on the link, I've multiple buttons, generated by php and mysql. if you click on them, the orange price change. through a javascript.
And if you click un the checkboxes also the price change through another javascript (yours).
Well, as you can see, they are in conflict and if I click on a ckeckbox the grey button will be reset, and viceversa.
Sorry for the multiple question I'm an architect with some basic html/css skills, and my boss gave me this big project and i'm trying to learn php, js and sql all in one :D

Comment: You need to click F12 and look in the console. You have an error here `$("#mq").html( $(this).' mq'+data('mq')  );` -  it should be `$("#mq").html( $(this).data('mq')  );`

Comment: @StefanoZanetti http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ch7vs39o/ - new code to handle clicks - I assume the buttons can only be clicked one at a time

Comment: Hi mplungjan, I cant' reach you through the form on your profile, so I write here again.
It seemes that, if I click first on the checkboxes, the total price of 200 (in your sample), and is reset to zero. in fact, after clicking un the 1000 checkbox i don't have 1200..

Comment: I assumed the price in the total field was matching any of the clicked boxes. We just need to save the basis price somewhere. I no longer read the price from the output

Comment: I updated the code in two places http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ch7vs39o/

Answer (score -3):

You can use Ajax. The main feature of AJAX is it make web-page faster, ajax allow reload only important part of web-page not complete website or web-page.